# Boost undefined reference error with boost::bind overloaded operators

Tags: c++, templates, boost, linker, boost-bind

The code in question:

```
boost::function<bool()> isSpecialWeapon = boost::bind(&WeaponBase::GetType,this) == WeaponType::SPECIAL_WEAPON;
```

The error I get is something like so:

```
 undefined reference to `boost::_bi::bind_t<bool, boost::_bi::equal, 
 boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::bind_t<WeaponType::Guns, 
 boost::_mfi::cmf0<WeaponType::Guns, WeaponBase>,  
 boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<WeaponBase*> > >, 
 boost::_bi::add_value<WeaponType::Guns>::type> > boost::_bi::operator==
 <WeaponType::Guns, boost::_mfi::cmf0<WeaponType::Guns, WeaponBase>, 
 boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<WeaponBase*> >, WeaponType::Guns>
 (boost::_bi::bind_t<WeaponType::Guns, boost::_mfi::cmf0<WeaponType::Guns, WeaponBase>, 
 boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<WeaponBase*> > > const&, WeaponType::Guns)'
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: @EmileCormier Trying to create a function that determines if the current object is of type X given that it can be of type {X,Y,Z}

Comment: Are you willing/able to use C++11 features?

Comment: @EmileCormier Sorry the system I am working on does not support C++11, else I would have used lamdas. Can you tell me if I am reading the documentaion wrong http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators

Comment: What compiler are you using?  From the documentation, it appears that it should work.  In that a bound functor compared to a value should return a new bind functor which does the comparison.

Comment: "gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-18) (GCC)" is the underlying compiler I belive

Comment: I couldn't get it working either with VS2010.

Comment: Ok, `boost::bind(...) == constant` is working for me now in VS2010. I must be losing my mind... Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get `boost::bind` to work as you desire, you can try Boost.Pheonix or Boost.Lamda as a workaround.

Try using `boost::pheonix::bind` (from [Boost.Pheonix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html)) instead of `boost::bind`:

```
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_member_function.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

enum WeaponType {melee, ranged, special};

class Sword
{
public:
    WeaponType GetType() const {return melee;}

    void test()
    {
        namespace bp = boost::phoenix;
        boost::function<bool()> isSpecialWeapon =
            bp::bind(&Sword::GetType, this) == special;
        std::cout << "isSpecialWeapon() = " << isSpecialWeapon() << "\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    Sword sword;
    sword.test();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you also use `boost::lambda::bind` (from [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/lambda.html)):

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>

enum WeaponType {melee, ranged, special};

class Sword
{
public:
    WeaponType GetType() const {return melee;}

    void test()
    {
        boost::function<bool()> isSpecialWeapon =
            boost::lambda::bind(&Sword::GetType, this) == special;
        std::cout << "isSpecialWeapon() = " << isSpecialWeapon() << "\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    Sword sword;
    sword.test();
}
```

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that the first statement in your code, produces a boost function instead of a boolean value. Am I reading the documentation wrong http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators

Comment: @user814628: I didn't know bind had support for operators. I've got something working with boost::phoenix and have updated my answer.

Comment: @user814628: Got it working with both Boost.Pheonix and Boost.Lambda. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: Awesome, its weird, I have to make sure my code works for two different platforms, the original code compiles in one platform but fails with the given error in the other. I want my code to be uniform, so so instead of having ifdefs for different platforms, I just created a local function instead of using the inline bind and that seems to work on both platforms. Thank you for your phoenix and lamda implementation. I will have to look into those namespace and see what's different or better about their bind.